# Place a empty array of image views on a view controller screen

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, insert, imageview

My code in swift starts off declaring an empty array of imageviews in var myArray. In view didload I tried to insert the first imageview at the beginning of the array. My code is not working there is a compile error at  `myArray.insert(UIImageView, at: 0)`.

Then there is a runtime error at  `myArray[0].frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-0, y: view.center.y+100, width: 50, height: 50)` where it state out of index range.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var myArray = [UIImageView]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myArray.insert(UIImageView, at: 0)
    [myArray[0]].forEach({
        $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemTeal
          self.view.addSubview($0)
      })
    myArray[0].frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-0, y: view.center.y+100, width: 50, height: 50)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert UIImageView() instead of UIImageView.

Try below code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var myArray = [UIImageView]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myArray.insert(UIImageView(), at: 0)
        myArray.forEach({
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemTeal
            self.view.addSubview($0)
        })
        myArray[0].frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x - 0, y: view.center.y + 100, width: 50, height: 50)
    }
}
```